# Update Dataset gridview using checkboxes

Tags: c#, dataset

I am working thru an exercise and I need to have a series of checkboxes, these checkboxes need to update the dataset based on which ones are checked, currently the code works but it removes the checked boxes not adds them:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(item.Text);
```

When I change it to this it breaks the code:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(item.Text);
```

Here is the full code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Configuration;


public partial class application_Crosswalk : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            Cache.Remove("CrosswalkSPS");

            DataSet ds = GetDataSet();
            chkColumns.DataSource = ds.Tables["CrosswalkSPS"].Columns;
            chkColumns.DataTextField = "ColumnName";
            chkColumns.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        DataSet ds = (DataSet)Cache["CrosswalkSPS"];

        // Contact the database if necessary.
        if (ds == null)
        {
            ds = RetrieveData();
            Cache.Insert("CrosswalkSPS", ds, null, DateTime.MaxValue,   TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
            lblCacheStatus.Text = "Created and added to cache.";
        }
        else
        {
            lblCacheStatus.Text = "Retrieved from cache.";
        }

        return ds;
    }

    // This method performs the database query, if the 
    // DataSet object isn't available in the cache.
    private DataSet RetrieveData()
    {
        string connectionString =     WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbbuddystring2"].ConnectionString;
        string SQLSelect = "SELECT * FROM CrosswalkSPS";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQLSelect, con);
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "CrosswalkSPS");
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }

        return ds;
    }

    protected void cmdFilter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = GetDataSet();

        // Copy the DataSet so the cached item isn't affected
        // when we remove columns.
         ds = ds.Copy();

        foreach (ListItem item in chkColumns.Items)
        {
             if (item.Selected)
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(item.Text);
            }
        }

        gridCustomers.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        gridCustomers.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the actual error returned?

Comment: System.Data.DuplicateNameException: A column named 'Common Career Technical Core' already belongs to this DataTable.

Comment: Could it be because its a copy and you aren't resetting `Cache["CrosswalkSPS"]` afterwards. I don't know I'm just guessing.

Answer (score 0):

Ah found it, I needed and !
       ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(!item.Text);